# ActiveReports 3 - Underlay Next property gets section partially printed

Tags: activereports

I have a report that has two headers. On the top one I have a subreport on the right side, that shows the report's main data. On the header below, I have two subreports. The one on the left has tabular information while the one on the right has more form-type info. This last subreport is set to match the upper header report width and position on the page.

Now, the top header is set as UnderlayNext = true, so it gets printed side by side with the tabular report. All is well except when the footer section of the subreport on the left does not fit on the page it is supposed to be printed and is moved to the next page. When that happens, the upper header section only gets partially printed, with the same height as the footer section of the other report.

---

**EDIT:** Rethinking (but not retesting) I think that what's going on is that the section set to underlay next does not go beyond the next section, thus when the section is not large enough, it gets cropped. In my case, the second section is larger than the UnderlayNext (top) one, but as I have a new page and the top section is set to repeat on every page, it gets cropped too. Funny thing is that if I select the data on the generated PDF, the information IS there, just not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to add an empty group footer section with size zero at the bottom of the report and set PrintAtBottom to true.

Answer (score 0):

It would be suggested to set the KeepTogether property to "True" and the GroupKeepTogether property to "All" of the GroupHeader.

Regards,
Mohita